# How to zoom in/out an image on clicking zoom in/out button in SDI?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am new to VC++.
How to zoom in/out an image on clicking zoom in/out button in SDI.

Comment: You need to write some code. What have you got so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to derive your document view class from [`CScrollView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/3t073d82.aspx) instead of the default `CView` created by the wizard. Use the `SetScrollSizes()` member function to set the zoom level. You could use `SetScaleToFit()` initially to define 100% zoom. In `OnDraw()` use `CDC::StretchBlt()` to actually draw the image to the size you have set via `SetScrollSizes()`.

Comment: wow, sometimes i'm surprised how people can provide such detailed answer to these so broad questions =)

Comment: thanks. :) you just need to have gone that path once to know.